# Windows 8 SDK (C#) Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a settings class. This class Gets and Sets values from the IsolatedStorages

```
    public Settings() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            // Get the settings for this application. 
            settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString()); 
        } 
    } 


    public int CookieCountSetting 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return GetValueOrDefault<int>(CookieCountSettingKeyName, CookieCountSettingDefault); 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (AddOrUpdateValue(CookieCountSettingKeyName, value)) 
            { 
                Save(); 
            } 
        } 
    }
    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value) 
    { 
        bool valueChanged = false; 

        // If the key exists 
        if (settings.Contains(Key)) 
        { 
            // If the value has changed 
            if (settings[Key] != value) 
            { 
                // Store the new value 
                settings[Key] = value; 
                valueChanged = true; 
            } 
        } 
        // Otherwise create the key. 
        else 
        { 
            settings.Add(Key, value); 
            valueChanged = true; 
        } 

        return valueChanged; 
    } 



    public valueType GetValueOrDefault<valueType>(string Key, valueType defaultValue) 
    { 
        valueType value; 

        // If the key exists, retrieve the value. 
        if (settings.Contains(Key)) 
        { 
            value = (valueType)settings[Key]; 
        } 
        // Otherwise, use the default value. 
        else 
        { 
            value = defaultValue; 
        } 

        return value; 
    }
```

// I have the save function too and some other non relevant code

Now in my code I use this class, and set a variable from the storage

```
    private Settings settings = new Settings(); 

    public int CookieCount; 

    public Game() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 


        CookieCount = settings.CookieCountSetting;
```

Eventually I want to store this value when the App closes/exits. I use this code for it

```
    // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background) 
    // This code will not execute when the application is closing 
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        settings.CookieCountSetting = CookieCount; 
    } 

    // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back) 
    // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated 
    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e) 
    { 
        settings.CookieCountSetting = CookieCount; 
    }
```

My problem is that when I close the App, and start it again, the value is back to its default value.

I see no way why this is the fact.

Comment: This is on an emulator. The only problem is the Application_Deactivated and Closing. Those simply do not get fired. Its not a storage problem.

Comment: Do you still have the events wired in either your xaml (<shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>) or in code?

Comment: Store the values directly after they are changed. This avoids hassle with the new App lifecycle.